# Prevent jquery action on particular div element

Tags: jquery, show-hide

ok this is what im doing :

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani/DFNhu/)

As you see , if u click on "This is some text" the toggle of table is perfect , but when i click on go , i dont want the table to toggle , i just want to goto the javascript function and do the intended action , i dont wish for the table to be displayed when i click the go button.If i click anywhere else other than the button , ie beyond the button go or anywhere else in the `<div>` the table show toggle , how can i prevent this ?

Comment: Yor button is inside the div sample and so when you click anywhere inside the sample div it will toggle.

Comment: precisely my question is how can i prevent that, i.e prevent the jquery intended action for a particular div element\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery click for your button too and e.stopPropagation inside.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#sample').click(function(){
    $('#dynamic_text').toggle();
});
$('#demo').click(function(e){
    alert("button click");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});​
```

Here's jsfiddle for your reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/DFNhu/12/

Comment: the stop Propagation will prevent me from executing the onclick function - do_something() also !

Comment: move your onclick do_something before stopPropagation instead of alert

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#sample').click(function(e){
           if(e.target == this)
           {
              $('#dynamic_text').toggle();
           }
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DFNhu/13/